# Reverse matching Express routes to database entries

Tags: node.js, regex, express, acl

I'm trying to build a sort of database-based ACL for my Express application. I currently have a Permissions table in the database that contains something like that:

- Resource: `*`
- Method: `*`
- RoleID: `1`
- isAllowed: `true`

---

- Resource: `/users`
- Method: `GET`
- RoleID: `2`
- isAllowed: `false`

---

- Resource: `/users/id/*`
- Method: `GET`
- RoleID: `2`
- isAllowed: `true`

My aim is to build a middleware that checks on the request object and allows or denies the route based on the rules in the database. My practical problem is, how do I match, say `/users/id/1` with the database entry `/users/id/*`? If I use the database entry as the basis for my regex, then `/users/id/1` is clearly matched, however, I don't think it's practical to pull and test ALL database entries for each request. What do you think would be the best approach to obtain the right rule from the database based on the requested URL?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a bit of thinking and research, I've discovered that you can use regular expressions in MySQL queries, so I've come up with this middleware (I'm using Sequelize):

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  // If a wildcard is in place, skip the rest
  return models.Permissions.findAll({
    where: {
      resource: '*',
      GID: req.session.role,
      isAllowed: 1
    }
  }).then(function (result) {
    if (result[0]) {
      return next()
    }

    // If the URL contains more than one element, replace the last item with [item, *]
    // to match eventual wildcards in the database entries
    let urlItems = req.url.split('/').filter(Boolean)
    let url = req.url
    if (urlItems.length > 1) {
      let lastItem = '[' + urlItems[urlItems.length - 1] + ', *]'
      url = req.url.split('/')
      url[url.length - 1] = lastItem
      url = url.join('/')
    }

    let query = 'SELECT * FROM Permissions '
    query += 'WHERE resource RLIKE "^' + url + '?$" '
    query += 'AND GID = ' + req.session.role

    return models.sequelize.query(query, {
      type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    }).then(function (result) {
      let policy = result[0]

      function return403 () {
        res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
      }

      // Forbid everything by default
      if (!policy) {
        return403()
        return
      }

      let methods = policy.method.toUpperCase().split(' ')

      // Forbid all methods which are not allowed
      if (policy.method === '*' || methods.includes(req.method)) {
        if (!policy.isAllowed) {
          return403()
          return
        }
      }

      // When other methods are explicitly allowed, forbid everything else
      if (policy.method !== '*' && !methods.includes(req.method) && policy.isAllowed) {
        return403()
        return
      }

      // Standard behaviour: allow explicitly allowed methods (or *) that are allowed.
      next()
    })
  })
}
```